# "unknown GLU entry gluOrtho2D" using opengl in Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell

I'm on Ubuntu 11.10 using ghc version 7.0.3.20110330, running "current-version updates" of nvidia display driver. You can reproduce by running:

```
curl http://ix.io/1t6 > Stroke.hs; ghc --make Stroke.hs; ./Stroke
...
Stroke: user error (unknown GLU entry gluOrtho2D)
```

But I can run opengl and it works fine. I tried glxgears and it ran fine and I ran an opengl benchmark and it worked fine as well.

Versions of haskell opengl libs
result of running:

```
for p in OpenGL OpenGLRaw GLURaw; do ghc-pkg latest $p; done

OpenGL-2.4.0.1
OpenGLRaw-1.1.0.1
GLURaw-1.1.0.0
```

Comment: I'm having same issue and the patching don't work. (I patched all 3 choices in HSGLURaw.c) ghc 7.0.3,
OpenGL-2.4.0.2,
OpenGLRaw-1.1.0.2,
GLURaw-1.1.0.1,
ubuntu 11.10. Circle: user error (unknown GLU entry gluOrtho2D) Even linking with -l flags is not resolving.

Comment: I have the same error with gluPerspective instead of gluOrtho2D. Using OpenGL-2.4.0.2, OpenGLRaw-1.1.0.2, GLURaw-1.1.0.1 and ubuntu 11.10

Comment: For me (Ubuntu 11.10, ghc-7.4.1) this is fixed with these versions: OpenGLRaw-1.2.0.0
GLURaw-1.2.0.0
OpenGL-2.5.0.0

Comment: getting the same issues, patch and -l options didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a definite bug. There is a problem with the linker (and I'm not sure if this is specific to 11.10 or to GHC 7.0+). Here's how it was explained to me: the linker essentially decides that, since you're not linking statically to libglut,  it will just optimize by not linking your executable to it at all. You can get around this by applying the following patch to GLURaw 1.1.0.0:

```
diff -ur GLURaw-1.1.0.0.orig/cbits/HsGLURaw.c GLURaw-1.1.0.0/cbits/HsGLURaw.c
--- GLURaw-1.1.0.0.orig/cbits/HsGLURaw.c    2011-05-12 09:02:30.000000000 +1200
+++ GLURaw-1.1.0.0/cbits/HsGLURaw.c 2011-05-11 23:08:10.000000000 +1200
@@ -68,6 +68,9 @@

 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <dlfcn.h>
+#include <stdio.h>
+#include <GL/glu.h>
+

 void*
 hs_GLU_getProcAddress(const char *name)
@@ -80,6 +83,7 @@
     /* Get a handle for our executable. */
     handle = dlopen(NULL, RTLD_LAZY);
   }
+  printf("%p\n", gluBeginCurve);

   return handle ? dlsym(handle, name) : NULL;
 }
Only in GLURaw-1.1.0.0: dist
```

Run `cabal install` on GLURaw after applying this patch, and it should get rid of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I get it works changing compile step to:

```
ghc --make Stroke.hs -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

I have the versions (I have not installed OpenGLRaw, GLURaw):

```
cabal list *

* OpenGL
    Default available version: 2.4.0.1
    Installed versions: 2.2.3.0
* OpenGLRaw
    Default available version: 1.1.0.1
    Installed versions: [ Not installed ]
* GLURaw
    Default available version: 1.1.0.0
   Installed versions: [ Not installed ]
```

EDIT: I'm using **Ubuntu 11.04** and **GHC 7.0.3** with **Haskell Platform 2011.2.0.1**

Answer (score 0):

I compiled it on my system (Mac OS 10.7.2 with GHC 7.2.1) and it worked here, so the program should be correct. My package versions are

```
GLURaw-1.1.0.0
GLUT-2.2.2.0
OpenGL-2.4.0.1
OpenGLRaw-1.1.0.1
```

Perhaps you could try finding a simple C/C++ example that uses `gluOrtho2D` and see if that works?

Comment: Yes, I know the program is correct. The question is... how do I figure out why it won't run on my system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the use of GLU has been largely deprecated as of OpenGL 3.0, from which greater versions have been in use since Haskell's OpenGL-2.4 packages. There's a mention on the [OpenGL wiki](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GluPerspective_code) that says:

> GLU - the OpenGL Utility library is an additional library that
>   contains a handful of functions for additional tasks. It was
>   traditional and can be found in a lot of tutorials and examples. But
>   GLU uses a lot of OpenGL features that are deprecated now. The
>   internal projection matrix should not be used anymore, so the
>   programmer should use a replacement for gluPerspective, that instead
>   of updating the internal projection matrix will return this matrix.

This would indicate that functions in `Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GLU.Matrix` should no longer be used. This includes:

```
ortho2D
perspective
lookAt
pickMatrix
project
unProject
unProject4
```

I suspect that this might be why your code compiles, but fails when `ortho2D` is used.

It might be tempting to use [`glOrtho`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml)  instead of [`gluOrtho2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluOrtho2D.xml), since we have:

```
ortho2D left right bottom up = ortho left right bottom up (-1) 1
```

However, according to the [OpenGL spec](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/gl.spec), it seems that even `glOrtho` is deprecated as of OpenGL 3.1. At the time of writing, using `ortho` instead of `ortho2D` works using this equivalence.

I noticed that one commenter also had troubles with the `perspective` function. Here's one way to implement it yourself without using GLU (but still using a function deprecated in OpenGL 3.1):

```
import qualified Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL as GL

perspective :: GL.GLdouble -> GL.GLdouble -> GL.GLdouble -> GL.GLdouble -> IO ()
perspective fovy aspect near far =
  GL.frustum xmin xmax ymin ymax near far
 where ymax = near * tan (fovy * pi / 360.0)
       ymin = - ymax
       xmax = ymax * aspect
       xmin = ymin * aspect
```